# ¿Cómo hago para relacionar diferentes clases en java?

Tags: java, poo, class

Ejemplos: problemas del tipo poner notas a alumnos en distintas asignaturas

### Hasta ahora se trabajar con una sola clase pero me han dicho que no es lo correcto

Cree un programa que defina una estructura con los nombres de los empleados en una tienda de computadoras. Además del nombre, sabemos cuántas unidades de cada tipo de productos ha vendido el vendedor. Además, piense en una estructura para almacenar el precio de € por cada tipo de producto.

*Por un lado tendría la clase alumno,clase notas y clase asignatura
como hago para relacionar las diferentes clases?

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], de paso revisa el [tour] una vez hecho lo anterior; edita tu pregunta y coloca que llevas hecho y donde tienes dudas

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es **herencia**. Además que debes plantear correctamente tu pregunta. Hablas sobre notas de alumnos y después hablas sobre una tienda de computadoras y sus empleados. Después hablas sobre ventas...

Imaginemos un escenario donde requieres que una clase herede atributos (variables de instancia y/o métodos) para evitar escribir de más.

**Estudiante.java**

```
package test;

public class Estudiante {
 /*Estas variables serán heredadas a EstuudianteSecundaria  y EstudiantePreparatoria*/
  private long id;
  private String nombre;
  private String apelllidos; 
  private List<String> materias;

  /*Este método será heredado a EstudianteSecundaria y EstudiantePreparatoria*/
  public double getPromedio(){
      double promedio = 0.0;
      //...
      return promedio;
  }

}
```

**EstudianteSecundaria.java**

```
package test;

public class EstudianteSecundaria extends Estudiante {

  //...
}
```

**EstudiantePreparatoria.java**

```
package test;

public class EstudiantePreparatoria extends Estudiante {

  //...
}
```

**Test.java**

```
 //Instanciar
    EstudianteSecundaria estudianteSecundaria;
    EstudiantePreparatoria estudiantePreparatoria;

    estudianteSecundaria = new EstudianteSecundaria();

    estudiantePreparatoria = new EstudiantePreparatoria();
//Hacer operaciones...
```

Básicamente la herencia consiste en crear clases (subclases) tomando como base otra clase (**superclase**), permitiendo así compartir datos y métodos.

Comment: Antes que nada gracias por responder. Voy a mirar lo que me dices. Lo que yo puse eran distintos ejemplos: vendedores(nombre, id, et) venden, una cantidad de productos. Alumnos, cursan asignaturas y tienen una determinadas notas(sacar promedios y cosas asi). Si yo trabajo con distintas clases como hago para relacionarlas entre si?

Comment: Lo que estás buscando se llama acoplamiento. https://preparandoscjp.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/orientacion-a-objetos-viii-acoplamiento-y-cohesion/